# Where does the Apple app Contacts store its files in Mavericks?

Tags: contacts

I'm making a clean re-install of Mavericks on a client's computer. I believe she had a large number of address book entries in the Contacts app that were not in iCloud, and I need to restore them from the backup. Where are they stored? I'm guessing they should be in Users/~/Library/ but I cannot find the location.

Comment: For precicely this reason, I have a recurring task to export both my contacts and calendar data to the archive format so I don't need to mess with the internal database state on any particular build. They are so small, I generally keep three or more years of data in my Backup folder on the filesystem. If your hand-migration fails, you can always restore from that backup and re-export things to a flat file or add that to your list of steps before the next clean install.

Comment: My hand-migration seems to have failed. See my comment on the answer below.

Comment: I'm not surprised. I've seen conflicts between the application saved state (~/Library/Containers) and database storage files (~/Library/Application Support) and sync sources (iCloud is all over the place). In your case, the problems that led you to seek a clean install might also have affected the files. I've had much better luck just restoring the entire user account to a new user folder and then exporting the data. How exactly was the "backup" made? (p.s. you might just accept this answer since it's where the data lies and ask a follow on question with the real problem - how to recover)

Comment: I cloned the entire hard disk using CCCloner.

Comment: Boot from the clone and export the contacts to a flat file. At that point oh can boot back to the clean system and import the data after wiping the failed hand migration.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no help. She has a 12MB address book database but since she upgraded to Mavericks recently, it only shows about 15 addresses. It appears to have failed weeks before I got here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contacts.app stores its data in **~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook**.

For the individual databases, you can list them using the following command:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/ -name "AddressBook-v22.abcddb"
```

Comment: Great. I have found the folder. But Contacts will not import the 16MB of files for this user. I can copy the entire folder from the backup to the new installation, but Contacts shows the same 15 addresses no matter what I do. With 16MB of data in there, there must be hundreds of addresses. What am I overlooking?

Comment: @WheatWilliams Are the contacts on the On My Mac user? Make sure this account is enabled in the Contacts.app preferences as I believe 'account enabled' states are stored elsewhere as they are used for other features.

Comment: Yes, of course , the contacts are on the On My Mac but there are no preferences to set. And Mavericks automatically re-enables iCloud in Contacts every time you restart, and some local cache shows up in Contacts, even though I have unplugged the Ethernet cable.

Comment: Still applicable to 10.13.x (High Sierra)? The above directory exists on my 10.13 MacBook.

Comment: @Johnny Indeed, still applicable in macOS 10.13 and macOS 10.14 at the time of writing